# parsing url in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, parsing, url

I am new to angularjs, and have a web application. I have searched on internet but couldn't find a mature library for parsing URL's in angularjs. Would someone know about one?

Something on the lines of 'urlparse' in python or Apache's 'httpcomponents' in java.

Comment: what do you mean by passing url?

Comment: "parsing" not "passing". eg. 'url-parse' nodejs library.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific to Angular, unless you want to wrap the functionality into Angular filter. Any third-party JS library can be used.

It can be [URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/) or more lightweight [js-url](https://github.com/websanova/js-url).

Comment: Thanks for the direction- finally settled on js-url. Really appreciate the help!